# What am i doing wrong here? in bash random

Tags: bash

I am trying to make random colour output string 
my file name is abc and the command i am entering is `abc RANDOM love_bash`

```
color=(0;30 0;31 0;32 0;33 0;34 0;35 0;36 0;37)
color2=${#color[*]}

input='^random$'
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $1 =~ $input ]]; then
        echo -ne '\e['${color[$((RANDOM%color2))]}m
        exit 2
fi
```

when i enter the command to get a random output i get

```
./echoc: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./echoc: line 22: `color=(0;30 0;31 0;32 0;33 0;34 0;35 0;36 0;37)'
./echoc: line 42: RANDOM%color2: division by 0 (error token is "color2")
```

Comment: Array indices are already evaluated in an arithmetic context; no need for `$((...))` here.

Answer (score 2):

`;` is a command terminator in `bash`; you need to quote it as part of an array element.

```
color=("0;30" "0;31" ... )
```

Comment: Thanks, cant believe i did not see that

Answer (score 1):

What I would do instead :

```
tput setaf  $(( ( RANDOM % 7 ) + 1 ))
echo foobar
tput sgr0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with '' around ANSI color codes and it works :

```
color=('0;30' '0;31' '0;32' '0;33' '0;34' '0;35' '0;36' '0;37' '1;30' '1;31' '1;32' '1;33' '1;34' '1;35' '1;36' '1;37')

color2=${#color[*]}

input='^random$'
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $1 =~ $input ]]; then
        echo -ne '\e['${color[RANDOM%color2]}m
        exit 2
fi
```